# Converting dictionary into list of nested dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of the dictionary and other list `List_1=[D1,D2,D3]`. My list of dictionary  test_dict is like:`

```
[{"D1": 1.0,"D2": 0},{"D4":1.2,"D2":1.4}]
```

What I want in my final_dict is:

```
[{"List_1":D1,"value":1.0,"List_1":D2,"value":0},{"Default":D4,"value":1.2,"List_1":D2,"value":1.4}]
```

In test_dict at index zero i have a dictionary having D1 and D2 as key and 1.0 and 0 are there values.But in my final_dict. I want to change my key value pair.
My final goal is to insert it into mongodb [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55052488/dictionary-inside-dictionary-insertion-in-mongodb)

Comment: To begin with, there are two `List_1` in the first `dict` of your expected output, which will be overwritten. Secondly, please rephrase your question to make it more clear; do you want to put `dict` into `dict`? or get value `D1` from input and use that?

Answer (score 0):

Key should not be the same in a dictionary else the values will get overwritten.
For example, the output of your expectation will be:-

```
{'List_1': 'D2', 'value': 0}
```

So, you need to assign values with different keys.